# Хранение каталога в современных интернет-магазинах

Tags: sql, nosql, ecommerce, eav

Ребята расскажите кто сталкивался практикуется ли такое в современных разработках.

Если для хранения каталога товаров и характеристик взять классическую EAV, а для оптимизации поиска и отбора по фильтрам этих товаров использовать уже Elasticsearch или же MongoDB. Например EAV хранится в SQL и обеспечивается структура и целостность данных всего каталога, при этом по определенным событиям, в фоне происходит миграция товаров в noSQL базу с которой уже работает фронт.

Такое вообще жизнеспособно и применяется на практике?
Моя конечная задача получить быстрый и гибкий поиск по характеристикам товаров.